# STM32 Eclipse + ARM GNU toolchain error linker

Tags: eclipse, linker, arm, embedded, stm32

I use Eclipse + ARM plugin to build my projects. When I needed to use in my project the StemWin library, I configured my IDE to use external library.

I set
Preferences -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols

I added in "Library Paths" the link to my folder includes library.
I also added the name of my library in tab "Library".
I checked the settings in the compiler tab and I ascertained all should be good.
When I tried to build my project I got an error from linker:

```
cannot find -lMyLib.a   Hello           C/C++ Problem
```

I double checked the name of my library and link, all are correct. This is the output of my linker:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -L"C:\lib" 
-T"C:\arm_toolchain\stm32_workspace\Hello\LinkerScript.ld" -Wl,
-Map=output.map -Wl,--gc-sections -o "Hello.elf" @"objects.list" -lMyLib.a
```

What should I do from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem before.

```
-l:STemWin526_CM4_GCC.a  
-L"C:\Edu_Workspace\STM32F4\stm32f4_bsp_template\Drivers\Middlewares\ST\STemWin\Lib"
```

Above are my working settings.

With `-l:<archive file name>` the colon `:` is important for archive file linking.

And `-L` will contain library path.
Also for stemwin make sure to compile with hardware floating point

```
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
```

Answer (score 1):

the convention for the `-l` option of the linker (say you give `-lMyLib.a` as a linker option)  is to search for a library file with "`lib`" prepended to the given name and `.a` (or `.so`) appended, i.e. your command line searches for a file `libMyLib.a.{a,so}` which is probably not how it's named.

Either you rename your library according to this convention or give it to the linker command line omitting `-l` (provided your IDE allows you to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in  `-lMyLib.a` which means you're trying to link a *static library* as a dynamic one.

To link a static lib you have to use its path as with ordinary `.o` files: `... /path/to/MyLib.a`

and the resulting command line should look something like

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -L"C:\lib" -T"C:\arm_toolchain\stm32_workspace\Hello\LinkerScript.ld" -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--gc-sections -o "Hello.elf" @"objects.list" /path/to/MyLib.a
```

**UPDATE:**

Although it might fix the issue, turns out it's not true:

> -llibrary
>
> -l library
>
> ...
> Normally the files found this way are library files—archive files whose members are object files. The linker handles an archive file by scanning through it for members which define symbols that have so far been referenced but not defined. But if the file that is found is an ordinary object file, it is linked in the usual fashion. The only difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches several directories.

(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: this has nothing to do with "static" or "dynamic" libs. The conventions with `-l` are the same for both.